# Razor - Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+200E

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

In Asp.Net core MVC [aspnetboilerplate.com], I want to print list of number for chart values,
Create values in string like this:

```
        var chartData_1 = "[";
        foreach (var item in daies)
        {
            chartData_1 += _billRepository.GetAll().Where(o => o.UserId == AbpSession.UserId.Value && o.CreationTime.Date == item.Date).Sum(o => o.Amount) + ", ";
        }
        chartData_1 = chartData_1.Trim().Remove(chartData_1.Length - 2) + "]";
        profileViewModel.ChartData_1 = chartData_1;
```

in view file, Print this value like this

```
data:@Html.Raw(Model.ChartData_1)
```

but added unwanted character on before minus, and throw exception on page
[[image: see image]]

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+200E
```

Comment: Try adding `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` after `.Sum(o => o.Amount)`.

Comment: @aaron It's correct! can you explain more? what is reason? is about aspnetboilerplate?

Comment: aspnetboilerplate sets `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, but the character is likely added by the dotnet runtime when rendering the amount.